# In Julia display a text file to the REPL

Tags: julia

Given a text file, "hello.jl" in the current directory:

```
" Example hello world program."
function hello()
    println("hello, world")
end
```

how would you display this to the Julia 1.0.0 REPL?

This is what I have so far:

```
julia> disp(f) = for line in readlines(open(f)); println(line); end
disp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> disp("hello.jl")
" Example hello world program."
function hello()
        println("hello, world")
end
```

Is there a built-in command to do this in Julia?

Comment: I would do `cat hello.jl` in the shell mode instead.

Comment: Or also `disp(file) = (println.(readlines(file)); nothing)`, using broadcasting syntax, notice how `readlines` also handles opening and reading a file, without needing to use `open`.

Comment: @Gnimuc Yes, I just tried it and it works well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the julia REPL, hit

```
;
```

to get to the REPL's built-in shell mode, then

```
shell> head path/to/my/filename
```

Comment: I think in this case the OP needs,`cat`, not `head`.

Comment: Just how I do it in Linux--with a unknown length file it might be safer to use head or head -n.

Comment: If the file size is a worry then `less` is also a good option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `run` function and pass it a `Cmd` argument, in Linux, to run the `cat` system command.

Type semicolon `;` in order to change to **shell** mode:

```
shell> cat hello.jl
"Example hello world program."
function hello()
    println("hello, world")
end
```

Use the `run` function to execute a command outside of Julia:

```
julia> run(`cat hello.jl`)  # Only works on Unix like systems.
"Example hello world program."
function hello()
    println("hello, world")
end
Process(`cat hello.jl`, ProcessExited(0))
```

In Windows the `type` command should be analogous to Unix `cat`:

```
julia> show_file(path::AbstractString) = run(@static Sys.isunix() ? `cat $path` : `type $path`)
show_file (generic function with 1 method)
```

`run` returns the `Process` object:

```
julia> show_file("hello.jl")
"Example hello world program."
function hello()
    println("hello, world")
end
Process(`cat hello.jl`, ProcessExited(0))
```

Use semicolon `;` at the end of the line, to suppress the return output in the REPL:

```
julia> show_file("hello.jl");  
"Example hello world program."
function hello()
    println("hello, world")
end
```

Or you could just return `nothing` at the end of `show_file` if you like.

Answer (score 3):

`println(String(read("hello.jl")))`

or

`"hello.jl" |> read |> String |> println`

Comment: `read` also has a method `read(filename::AbstractString, ::Type{T}) where T`, that does the string conversion in one step: `read("hello.jl", String)`.

Comment: `println(String(read("hello.jl")))` works well.  `"hello.jl" |> read |> String |> println` works as well.  `read("hello.jl", String)` works, but leaves escape characters in the string.

Comment: You can also do it in stream (do not read everything into memory at once): `write(stdout, open("hello.jl"))`